AgGrid React grid custom editor that handles onClick event and not onChange event: the editing is not being completed
I have create 2 custom AgGrid React grid editor componente:
One that hanles onChange and works:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, memo } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

const MinimalAgGridCellEditor2 = memo(forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(props.value);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        getValue() {
            return stateValue;
        },
        isCancelBeforeStart() {
            return false;
        },
        isCancelAfterEnd() {
            return false;
        }
    }));

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        //setStateValue('02');
        setStateValue(event.target.value)
        //props.stopEditing(); // Notify grid to stop editing
    };

    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                id={props.colDef.field}
                name={props.colDef.field}
                value={stateValue}
                fullWidth
                variant="standard"
                onChange={handleChange}
        />
        </>
    );
}));

export default MinimalAgGridCellEditor2;

And one that handles onClick and does not work:
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, memo } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';

const MinimalAgGridCellEditor = memo(forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    const [stateValue, setStateValue] = useState(props.value);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        getValue() {
            return stateValue;
        },
        isCancelBeforeStart() {
            return false;
        },
        isCancelAfterEnd() {
            return false;
        }
    }));

    const handleFieldClick = () => {
        setStateValue('02');
        props.stopEditing(); // Notify grid to stop editing
    };

    return (
        <>
            <TextField
                id={props.colDef.field}
                name={props.colDef.field}
                value={stateValue}
                fullWidth
                InputProps={{
                    readOnly: true,
                }}
                variant="standard"
                onClick={handleFieldClick}
            />
        </>
    );
}));

export default MinimalAgGridCellEditor;

I am hosting components in the grid column definition as:
   { field: 'project', headerName: 'Project', width: 150, sortable: true, filter: true, editable: true, valueSetter: handleCellValueUpdate,
      cellEditor: MinimalAgGridCellEditor2
    },

and the handler is:
  const handleCellValueUpdate = (event) => {
    alert({
      cd_sal_doc_line_pos: event.data.cd_sal_doc_line_pos,
      field: event.colDef.field,
      value: event.newValue,
      componentKey: componentKey,
    });
    setSalDocLinePosFieldValue({
      cd_sal_doc_line_pos: event.data.cd_sal_doc_line_pos,
      field: event.colDef.field,
      value: event.newValue,
      componentKey: componentKey,
    })
    return true;
  }

THe problem is that onChange approach generate handleCellValueUpdate event and does it even automatically, but onClick approach does not generate this even in the case when the actual finalization is being done.
Of course, my onClick scenario is just minimal example, actually I am planning to open popper and select value from it (popper will have serach fields, etc) and such changes will not happen on onChange, but on other events. That is why I am doing this minimalistic example.
Also, I am using Material-UI components.
